# Can we use Fluent UI react with C++ application?

Tags: winapi, office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, fluentui-react, office-ui-fabric-react

We are building a cpp application for Windows desktop with modern look and feel.

I read about how Office apps are built using and got to know that it is built using [Fluent UI react V8](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui#fluent-ui-web).

And I also went through `Excel.exe.mannifest` file in my system and noticed that Excel is win32 style application.
[image]

So is wanted to understand how to create a C++ Win32 style app and use Fluent UI React in it.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to build a Windows (desktop) app with modern look & feel, you want to use WinUI3 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/composition https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/visual-layer (or UWP). Fluent UI React is for web apps. You can't have 100% both. You could also use Electron https://www.electronjs.org/ to have a pseudo Win32 app with web components. Lots of apps use Electron (like current Teams version)

Comment: Thank you for the response @SimonMourier , what does having a "pseudo" Win32 app with electronjs mean?

Comment: An Electron app is based on Chromium and Node.js so it's a web app to start with, but it's also deployed locally so you can have access to desktop APIs like Windows API.